# Filtering MySQL data in PHP to only show data of the current session's user?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the following PHP script that selects MySQL data and displays all the different users' data in a table.

What I need is to limit this data to only that of the logged-in user for that session. As in only the single ID, name and email of the person logged in instead of the table showing all user data.

I assume I need to "SELECT * FROM usertable where (something) = (something)", I'm just not sure where to go from here.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","myusername","mypassword","mydatabase");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM usertable");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Email</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['emailaddress'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: You can use `WHERE`. `"SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE id = '".$_SESSION["id"]."'"`

Comment: as a newbie try to avoid `SELECT *` try using required field names instead of `*`, which can save a lot of time later and is more efficient.

Comment: @LoganWayne bit more readable version `"SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE id = '{$_SESSION['id']}'"`

Comment: Thank you for the advice. However, my table seems to be coming up empty. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

To clarify, the "id" within SESSION is the name of my session, right?

Here is my code for establishing the session if it helps

`<?php
 session_start();

 #check to see if session exists
 if (isset($_SESSION['firstname_dmeisli1'])){
  #there is a session
  $fn = $_SESSION['firstname_dmeisli1'];
  $displayLoggedIn = 'block';
  $displayNotLoggedIn ='none';
 
 }
 else {
  #no session
  $fn = '';
  $displayLoggedIn ='none';
  $displayNotLoggedIn = 'block';
 
 }
?>`
excuse my formatting

Answer (score 0):

### Hello!

---

Well you are right you need a `WHERE` clause there in your statement.

If you have someone logged in and are looking for that persons name is logged in first store the id in a variable such as a $_SESSION variable your statement would look like `SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE id = {$_SESSION['id']}`

So first you would need a function when a user logs to store it

```
$_SESSION['id'] = row['id']
```

or If your looking for a specific first/lastname combo:

```
"SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE firstname = '{$firstname}' AND lastname = '{$lastname}'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Do you think you could get more specific about storing the user session?

How would I incorporate that function when this is code establishing my session?

 `<?php`

 `session_start();`

 `if (isset($_SESSION['firstname_dmeisli1'])){`
  `$fn = $_SESSION['firstname_dmeisli1'];`
  `$displayLoggedIn = 'block';`
  `$displayNotLoggedIn ='none';`

 
 `}`
 `else {`
  `#no session`
  `$fn = '';`
  `$displayLoggedIn ='none';`
  `$displayNotLoggedIn = 'block';`
  
 `}`

`?>`

Thanks again, please excuse the formatting

Answer (score 0):

SESSION ID don't mean you need to make something like $_SESSION['user_id'].

Remember SESSION is like ghost, sometime it's can be lost with no trace. Try to used simple cookie to confirm session data store within database. Just make a limit to that cookie, so after several time, the cookie will be destroy and renew with complete diferent value.

For your question is simple,...

`SELECT * FROM 'tablename' WHERE 'table_field' LIKE 'table_value'`